# Some changes only showing up locally but not on heroku hosted webapp?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I changed the title in html and added a favicon, and those changes are only showing up locally. This is happening even when I have updated some text ("Testing 1 2 3" as shown):

[image]

However, when I update to github and push to heroku, I the text changes happen ("Testing 1 2 3") but the title and favicon don't show up:

[image]

I am also using incognito, so it can't be a problem with the cache, and I have the same problem on Firefox so it can't be the browser. What could the problem be?

Here is part of my html code:

```
  <html>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <head>
         <title>
            Opal Kale
         </title>
        <meta name="description" content="Senior at Cal studying CS. Welcome to my personal homepage.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Opal Kale">
        <link href='{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Codystar:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body id='home'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Kapil said, this isn't a problem with your code at all, but with your domain host. You registered your domain with one company, but your Heroku app runs on another domain.

You're using [cloaked redirection](http://www.thesitewizard.com/sitepromotion/cloaked-domain-redirection-issues.shtml) to point your URL at Heroku. This means your domain registrar isn't doing any DNS changes, but just creating a page with a frame inside of it that displays the contents of the other url.

You can see it if you curl the page:

```
>> curl http://www.opalkale.com/ 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<meta name="VERSION" content="">
<meta name="DATA" content="fwdnode7-bl.web-hosting.com (162.255.119.4)">
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://glacial-mesa-9513.herokuapp.com/" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.</h2><br><br>
<center>Click <a href="http://glacial-mesa-9513.herokuapp.com/" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
</noframes>
</html>
```

This method works, but it's a really cheap n' dirty way to do it. Your registrar has no idea what the content of that other page is, so that's why the title, favicon and anything else won't display properly.

The right way to do it is to have your domain registrar [point the URL at heroku's servers using DNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), but a lot of free domain registars won't do this.

Answer (score 1):

The source code on the site indicates that the html body is being rendered in a  tag that points to the heroku server. So the correct body is being rendered. But the header being rendered is the header on.

The title and favicon you wrote are being rendered in the  tag in the frame, but the  outside the  doesn't have the favicon or title tags, and that's the one the browser is reading.

I'm not sure what might have caused this, but your DNS / hosting settings are likely the thing to blame.